# How can i make people selected 2 choices between 3 options?

Tags: django

I want users to choice 2 selection of my checkbox how can i do that by using Django?
I ve tried that

**forms.py**

```
class KaydolForm(forms.ModelForm):
    secim = (('Bk','banka kartı'),('kk','Kredi Kartı'),('cek', 'çek'))
    secims=forms.ChoiceField(choices=secim, widget=forms.RadioSelect)
```

but i can choose only one of them

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/fields/#multiplechoicefield

Read this, in your form it would be like this:

```
class KaydolForm(forms.ModelForm):

    choices = (
        ('Bk', 'banka kart1),
        ('kk', 'Kredi'),
        ('cek', 'cek')
    )

    secims = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=choices)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a [`MultipleChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/fields/#multiplechoicefield). On this field you can select multiple options.

Then you should also use a widget (representation on webpage) that accepts multiple choices. You could use [`CheckboxSelectMultiple`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/widgets/#checkboxselectmultiple) or [`SelectMultiple`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/widgets/#selectmultiple)

So change your code to:

```py
class KaydolForm(forms.ModelForm): 
    
    choices_list = (('Bk','banka kartı'),('kk','Kredi Kartı'),('cek', 'çek'))
    choice_field = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=choices_list, widget=forms.SelectMultiple)
```

The user could now however check one, two or three options. You must write a own validator to check, if exactly two are checked. For more detail see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/validators/)